# Adding multiple entries in firebase at same time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to create an order using firebase database.

I need to perform following steps in overall operation

```
1- Update the balance of user 
2- Create a transaction with payment data
3- Create a record of order in orders listing
4- Update entries of local store.
```

Now all of these details must be performed together. What is the best approach to do this in firebase. either

```
ref1.setValue(
ref2.setValue(
ref3.setValue(
ref4.setValue(
```

or via transactions, and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment:

> The entires are not children of users, each is from different list. users, orders, transactions and stores

I recommend you to perform simultaneous updates to multiple locations in the JSON tree, with a single call to DatabaseReference's [updateChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) method.

An example from the [offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) would be:

```
private void writeNewPost(String userId, String username, String title, String body) {
    // Create new post at /user-posts/$userid/$postid and at
    // /posts/$postid simultaneously
    String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
    Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

> This example uses `push()` to create a post in the node containing posts for all users at `/posts/$postid` and simultaneously retrieve the key with `getKey()`. The key can then be used to create a second entry in the user's posts at `/user-posts/$userid/$postid`.

Simultaneous updates made this way are atomic: either all updates succeed or all updates fail.